# Optimization to find the change in input parameters that best explains a change in output parameters

Tags: optimization, notation

I have trouble formulating my problem in an understandable way. I want to find a difference in a simulated input parameter vector $\vec{p}_{simulation}$ which best explains a given difference of an measured output parameter vector $\vec{y}_{measurement}$. The function linking these two vectors is achieved with a numerical model, which I assume to be reasonable enough for the relevant effects.
I normalize the $\vec{y}$-vectors to make them comparable. This is how I would write the optimization goal, perhaps someone could help me with the notation:

$\Delta\vec{p}_{simulation} = min(||\Delta\vec{y}_{measurement}||_{max}-||\Delta\vec{y}_{simulation}||_{max})$

Does this kind of problem have a name?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a numerical model $\hat{y}(p)$ with some adjustable parameters $p$ and you want to find the vector of parameter values that get us as close as possible to the measured value $y$.

This is a very common problem in statistics and machine learning where you are setting a model's parameters based on how close the output gets to a target value.

In your case, you are trying to get the output $\hat{y}$ "close" to $y$ by adjusting $p$. However, it depends on how you define "close":

1. Absolute difference: $|\hat{y}(p)-y|$
2. Squared difference $(\hat{y}(p)-y)^2$

In fact, any *symmetric, non-negative* function $f(d)$ for a difference $d$ can serve as your definition of close that you want to minimize.

Your post is closest to (1) (you needed to include the absolute value so it doesn't go to $-\infty$).

How easy/hard this is depends on how convex your model is (i.e., does its graph resemble something like a parabola?) so it has a only one "hill" to climb (or bowl to descend here)? If so you'll be able to use a local numerical optimizer.

If you have many hills/bowls then you'll have to try with many starting points and hope you get convergence.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful! So it's not much of a difference,notationwise, if I want to adjust a parameter vector p or a change/differential of the parameter vector dp? And corresponding y and dy?

Comment: @meshWorker correct